# It is saying that the /dev/xdva1 doesn't exist?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am trying to see the free disk space in my ec2 instance and I am using this the command that aws tells you to use and it says that the directory doesn't exist.

That's the command

```
os.system('df -hT /dev/xvda1')
```

Error Message:

```
df: ‘/dev/xvda1’: No such file or directory
```

When I do `os.system('df -hT)` it returns:

```
Filesystem     Type  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root      ext4  5.9G  4.8G  1.1G  82% /
/dev/vdb       ext4  1.9G   45M  1.9G   3% /dev
/dev/loop0     ext4  526M  440K  514M   1% /tmp
```

The Instance says this:

```
Root device
/dev/xvda

Block devices
/dev/xvda
```

Comment: Does this command work? ```os.system('df -hT')```. If it does, that should return all of the available file systems on the OS. From there, you should be able to replace ```/dev/xvda1``` with a directory that does exist.

Comment: Yes, this is what it returnFilesystem                                                   Type  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root      ext4  5.9G  4.8G  1.1G  82% /
/dev/vdb       ext4  1.9G   45M  1.9G   3% /dev
/dev/loop0     ext4  526M  440K  514M   1% /tmp

Comment: In the AWS console, click on Volumes in the left hand menu, then the volume in question from the list. This should open a description tab at the bottom with an entry called ```Attachment Information```. Does this have a value?

Comment: My Instance Id and /dev/xvda (attached)

Comment: Why is this question tagged with `aws-lambda`? Is this code running on EC2 or Lambda?

Comment: I use the command on lambda

Comment: That command will never work on Lambda. Why are you looking at a volume in the EC2 console but trying to access the volume in Lambda?

Comment: What is a question about system administration doing on Stack Overflow anyhow? We have [unix.se] and [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) for that.

Answer (score 0):

`df` will accept a mountpoint. To query the free space on the root volume, just use `/`.

```
os.system('df -hT /')
```

Comment: I want to see the free space of one instance

Comment: @I_am_trying_my-best, `df` only looks at the single system it's running on. It will never give you information for any other instance.